# Extract data from alternate rows with python

Tags: python, parsing

I want to extract the number corresponding to O2H from the following file format (The delimiter used here is space):

```
# Timestep     No_Moles     No_Specs     SH2    S2H4    S4H6    S2H2    H2  S2H3    OSH2    Mo1250O3736S57H111  OSH S3H6    OH2 S3H4    O2S SH  OS2H3   
144500       3802         15     3639    113     1   10  18  2   7   1   3   2   1   2   1   1   1  
# Timestep     No_Moles     No_Specs     SH2    S2H4    S2H2    H2  S2H3    OSH2    Mo1250O3733S61H115  OS2H2   OSH S3H6    OS  O2S2H2  OH2 S3H4    SH  
149000       3801         15     3634    114     11  18  2   7   1   1   2   2   1   1   4   2   1  
# Timestep     No_Moles     No_Specs     SH2    OS2H3   S3H Mo1250O3375S605H1526    OS  S2H4    O3S3H3  OSH2    OSH S2H2    H2  OH2 OS2H2   S2H O2S3H3  SH  O4S4H4  OH  O2S2H   O6S5H3  O6S5H5  O3S4H4  O2S3H2  O3S4H3  OS3H3   O3S2H2  O4S3H4  O3S3H   O6S4H5  OS4H3   O3S2H   O5S4H4  OS2H    O2SH2   S2H3    O4S3H3  O3S3H4  O   O5S3H4  O5S3H3  OS3H4   O2S4H4  O4S4H3  O2SH    O2S2H2  O5S4H5  O3S3H2  S3H6    
589000       3269         48     2900    11  1   1   47  11  1   81  74  26  25  21  17  1   3   5   2   3   3   1   1   2   2   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   3   3   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1  
# Timestep     No_Moles     No_Specs     SH2    Mo1250O3034S578H1742    OH2 OSH2    O3S3H5  OS2H2   OS  OSH O2S3H2  OH  O3S2H2  O6S6H4  SH  O2S2H2  S2H2    OS2H    H2  OS2H3   O5S4H2  O7S6H5  S3H2    O2SH2   OSH3    O7S6H4  O2S2H3  O6S5H3  O2SH    O4S4H   O3S2H3  S2  O2S2H   S5H3    O7S4H4  O3S3H   OS3H    OS4H    O5S3H3  S3H O17S12H9    O3S3H2  O7S5H4  O4SH3   O3S2H   O7S8H4  O3S3H3  O11S9H6 OS3H2   S4H2    O10S8H6 O4S3H2  O5S5H4  O6S8H4  OS2 OS3H6   S3H3    
959500       3254         55     2597    1   83  119     1   46  59  172     4   3   4   1   27  7   38  6   23  3   1   2   3   5   3   1   2   1   2   1   1   6   3   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   3   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1
```

That is, all the alternate rows contain the corresponding data of its previous row.

And I want the output to look like this

```
1
4
21
83
```

How it should work:

```
1 (14th number on 2nd row which corresponds to 14th word of 1st row i.e. O2H)
4 (16th number on 4th row which corresponds to 16th word of 3rd row i.e. O2H)
21 (15th number on 6th row which corresponds to 15th word of 5th row i.e. O2H)
83 (6th number on 8th row which corresponds to 6th word of 7th row i.e. O2H)
```

I was trying to extract it using regex but couldnot do it. Can anyone please help me to extract the data?

Comment: You sure you want `O2H` and not `OH2`. There's no such string like `O2H` in the sample data you showed.

Comment: Thank you for correcting, it should be OH2. Sorry for my typing mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You easily parse this to a `dataframe` and select the desired column to fetch the values.

Assuming your data looks like the sample you've provided, you can try the following:

```
import pandas as pd

with open("data.txt") as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

header = max(lines, key=len).replace("#", "").split()
df = pd.DataFrame([line.split() for line in lines[1::2]], columns=header)
print(df["OH2"])
df.to_csv("parsed_data.csv", index=False)
```

Output:

```
0     1
1    11
2     1
3    83
Name: OH2, dtype: object
```

Dumping this to a `.csv` would yield:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response I tried your method but In the file, the position of OH2 is different in different rows. So the corresponding data did not match.

Comment: Can you please give me some insight on how can I rearrange that? TIA

Comment: If the position of OH2 diffrent, then why don't you update your question with the *actual data you work with*? I can't give any insight because I simply don't know what your data looks like. I've worked only with what you gave.

Comment: The data looks exactly like the one I have provided. According to your code, the answers are 1,11,1,83 (all the 6th number in the row) whereas they should be 1,4,21,83 (14th, 16th, 15th, 6th number in the row - which are the positions of OH2 of the previous rows). Can you please help?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I figured out the solution and commented.

Answer (score 1):

i think you want OH2 and not O2H and it's a typo. Assuming this:

(1) iterate every single line

(2) take in account only even lines. ( `if (line_counter % 2) == 0: continue` )

(3) splitting all the spaces and using a counter variable, count the index of the OH2 in the even line. assuming it is 14 in the first line

(4) access the following line ( +1 index ) and splitting spaces of the following line,  access the element at the index of the element that you find in point (3)

since you haven't post any code i assumed your problem was more about finding a way to achieve this, than coding, so i wrote you the algorithm

Comment: Thank you for providing the algorithm. I thought to do a similar thing myself but I am unsure of how to achieve the 3rd and 4th point of your provided algorithm. Can you please give some insight with python code?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I figured out the solution and commented.

Comment: @AbdullahArafat perfect. i saw you implemented something similar to my suggestion. i'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone, for the help, I figured out the solution

```
i=0
j=1
with open ('input.txt','r') as fin:
    with open ('output.txt','w') as fout:
        for lines in fin: #Iterating over each lines
            lists = lines.split() #Splits each line in list of words
            try:
                if i%2 == 0: #Odd lines
                    index_of_OH2 = lists.index('OH2')
                    #print(index_of_OH2)
                i=i+1
                if j%2 == 0: #Even lines
                    number_of_OH2 = lists[index_of_OH2-1]
                    print(number_of_OH2 + '\n')
                    fout.write(number_of_OH2 + '\n')
                j=j+1
            except:
                pass
```

Output:

```
1
4
21
83
```

try:, except: pass added so that if OH2 is not found in that line it moves on without error